Is it possible to put a variable together in every bivariate function?
$z=\frac{Ax}{By}$
By considering a new variable $X=\frac{x}{y}$, I can rebuild the bivariate function above to univariate function, $z=\frac{A}{B}X$
However, I cannot do the same thing to the function below.
$z=\frac{Ax+B+C}{Dy+E+F}$
What is the condition for rebuilding bivariate function to univariate function by introducing new variable like above.
Purpose: I want to make a graph with variables $x$, $y$, and $z(x,y)$ on plane.

There is always the trivial way: $z = X$. Or let $X$ be any bijective function applied to $z$. For a real solution to your problem we first need a definition, what an appropriate $X$ actually is.

$X$ must be a function consisted of only $x$ and $y$, without constant term (ex. $X=\frac{x}{y}$).  I want to know what kind of functions can be deformed like this.

I don't think it's feasible to define a "function without constant term" in a proper way. Is $X = x+y+1$ allowed? If no, what about $X = x + y + x/x$?
